How do I uninstall applications, Jopline?
I have installed the Joplin application as detailed below. I want to uninstall it completely. Already tried to uninstall using the terminal but that did not work.   -
Installation instruction :
wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laurent22/joplin/dev/Joplin_install_and_update.sh | bash

Uninstall Instruction:
sudo rm -r ~/.joplin
sudo rm -r ~/.config/joplin-desktop
sudo rm ~/.local/share/applications/appimagekit-joplin.desktop


That install scripts bases how/where it installs on your base OS/release, which we don't know, thus can't actually provide specific/accurate advice. We're limited to details you provide.

This post from the Joplin forum should do the trick. This suggests removing the directory ~/.config/joplin-desktop.

Removing the directory ~/.config/joplin-desktop should do the trick.
Credit: Joplin Forum

Hello, Graham, thanks for the advice ...the directory is deleted. Although the desktop icon is still there.

is the icon shown in the ~/Desktop folder? If so, delete it.
